# Re: Create Top and Side Menu

Tags: submenu

I am using ASP.NET MVC C# and am very new to programming and might get terminologies wrong.

After several online searches I am rather confused and would like some direction on how to get a new sub-menu to appear when I click on a menu-tab and how to have a side-bar menu to appear when I click on the sub-menu tab. 
In the image when a person clicks on "Employee" from the Top-Menu the below menu appears, How do I create this.
And when "Employee List" is clicked the side-menu appears, How do i create this.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3ngJ.png)

Thanking for your help in advance.

Regards,
Kyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can obviously not give you the exact code without knowing much more, but maybe you can include a `MenuId` parameter in your query string when a user has clicked on a menu item?

And if the `MenuId` parameter is present in the query string, display a submenu?

Your action in MVC could look like this, for instance:

```
public IActionResult MyPage(int menuId)
{
 ///your logic here
  var model = new Model();
  model.MenuId = menuId;
  return View(model);
}
```

and in your Razor View:

```
@if (Model.MenuId.HasValue)
{
    <ul>
     <li>This is my submenu</li>
     <li>Second menu item</li>
    </ul>
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: Thank-you for your response.

Comment: You're welcome. If it helped, you can accept my answer :-)

Comment: Hi  Steven Lemmens, yes of course I will accept your answer if I knew where the "Accept Answer" button was. I do not see where I can accept your answer.

Comment: I think it's a green checkmark next to my answer on the left. If you cannot find it, no worries though.

Comment: Hi  Steven, I found the "Accept Answer" and have accepted your answer. Thanks again for your help.